# Visual Studio Code git active account

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-repository

I'm trying to run a 'push' from Visual Studio Code to my Cloud Repository. I have changed my account, but when I do the push the following message appears: " Your current active account [OLD ACCOUNT] does not have any valid credentials".

I have tried all this things:
I have done 'gcloud auth login' and selected my actual account, says that I'm login.
In my Windows Credentials Manager the old account doesn't appear.
In my .gitconfig is only my new account.
When I do: 'git config --list' in my project folder, the account is my new account.

But despite all of this, when I do the 'push' in Visual Studio Code, still says that I'm using the old account.

Why is using the old one?

Answer (score 0):

It was into the local folder of the project .git/config the next line:
[credential] helper